# Identical results from random forest hyperparameter tuning in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am trying out hyperparameter tuning of randomforest in R using the library(RandomForest). Why am I getting identical results for different values of hyperparameter i.e. maxnodes?

I am using the Titanic dataset that was obtained from Kaggle. I applied grid search only on the hyperparameter 'mtry' and the results gave me different values of Accuracy and Kappa for each 'mtry'.

However, when I tried to search for the best 'maxnode' value, all of them return the same value of Accuracy and Kappa.

#### This is for tuning 'mtry'

```
library(randomForest)
control <- trainControl(
  method = "cv", 
  number = 10,
  search = "grid"
)

tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(1:10))
rf_mtry <- train(train_X,
                 train_Y,
                 method = "rf",
                 metric = "Accuracy",
                 tuneGrid = tuneGrid,
                 trControl = control,
                 importance = TRUE,
                 nodesize = 14,
                 ntree = 300
                 )
```

#### This is for tuning 'maxnodes'

```
mtry_best <- rf_mtry$bestTune$mtry

store_maxnode <- list()
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = mtry_best)
for (maxnodes in c(2:20)) {
  set.seed(1234)
  rf_maxnode <- train(train_X,
                      train_Y,
                      method = "rf",
                      metric = "Accuracy",
                      tuneGrid = tuneGrid,
                      trControl = control,
                      importance = TRUE,
                      nodesize = 5,
                      maxnodes = maxnodes,
                      ntree = 300
                      )
  current_iteration <- toString(maxnodes)
  store_maxnode[[current_iteration]] <- rf_maxnode
}
results_mtry <- resamples(store_maxnode)
summary(results_mtry)
```

I expected to see different values of Accuracy and Kappa for different maxnode, but they were identical.

Comment: How are you doing your splitting?  what is your seed?

Comment: I used createDataPartition to create a train and test set. The seed was set to seed(1234) that is within the FOR loop

Comment: @griffinleow did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same issues.